# Missing `.Relational()` method when migration from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm updating a project from 2.2 to 3.1 and I have the following method to automatically patch all `decimal` properties to use `decimal(18, 6)` sql type when creating new migrations.

```
    public static void PatchDecimalProperties(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var property in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?)))
        {
            property.Relational().ColumnType = "decimal(18, 6)";
        }
    }
```

Now in 3.1 the `IMutableProperty.Relational()` method does not exist anymore.

Is this method still exists or is there a replacement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using

```
property.Relational().ColumnType = "decimal(18, 6)";
```

you can use

```
property.SetColumnType("decimal(18, 6)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the *answer* is accepted. But this answer didn't work for me. Another approach worked for me. Sharing below, **maybe someone will need it**.

```
property.SetPrecision(18);
property.SetScale(6);
```